# How can I test email piping?

Tags: php, email, piping, email-forwarding

Apologies if this question is too broad, but I don't see how to troubleshoot this issue.

I have a forwarder set up in cPanel from an email address to `|/home/cffcdbfd/script.php`.

That script contains this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/php -q
<?php

$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$raw = "";
while ( !feof($fd) ) {
    $raw .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

mail("myemailaddress@gmail.com", "This is a test message", $raw);
?>
```

(The script and its directory have permissions 0755.)

When I forward an email to the email address set up, I don't receive anything at `myemailaddress@gmail.com`. This happens even if the code is just the mail function (with something static instead of `$raw`).

How can I test that the email is reaching the PHP script? I see a trace option in cPanel, but I'm not sure if it's relevant, or how to use it.

**Update**

I'm not sure about `#! /usr/bin/php -q`. I copied this from an online code snippet but I can't find any of these folders in my structure.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting?

Comment: @LukasMeine yes - the company told me email piping was possible with this plan

Comment: Hmm... Before anything else, you could use the logs to check if your script is being called at all. Do you have access to that in your cpanel?

Comment: @LukasMeine if I search 'log' in the file manager I get a directory called `/access-logs` but it's empty

Comment: try looking for a directory called error_log

Comment: Nope, no records found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162625/discussion-between-lukas-meine-and-sebastian).